# Oracle DB - Save Timestamp in Database

Tags: xml, database, oracle

i am receiving XML Data and i want to save the value
'2019-11-15T03:22:45.254+01:00' into my timestamp(6) database column!

how to i need to cast it?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to fit your value in the `TIMESTAMP(6)` data type column, You will need to use `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE` data type column to hold this value otherwise you will lose Time zone.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE(YOUR_TS_COL TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-11-15T03:22:45.254 +01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') );

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE;

YOUR_TS_COL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-NOV-19 03.22.45.254000 AM +01:00

SQL>
```

an example of using a column with the `TIMESTAMP(6)` only -- **you will lose the Time zone**

```
SQL> DROP TABLE YOUR_TABLE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE(YOUR_TS_COL TIMESTAMP(6));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE VALUES ( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-11-15T03:22:45.254 +01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') );

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE; 

YOUR_TS_COL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
15-NOV-19 03.22.45.254000 AM

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to amended your table to add a new `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column (please note the syntax).  For example below is the syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE test_table
ADD timestamp_tz_col TIMESTAMP (2) WITH TIME ZONE;
```

The `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type has its own flavour of the `to_timestamp` function. It’s called `to_timestamp_tz`.

Your `insert` query will look something like below:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (timestamp_tz_col)
VALUES (to_timestamp_tz('2019-11-15T03:22:45.254 +01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') );
```

Comment: Format string is wrong! i need to convert "2019-11-15T03:22:45.254+01:00"

Comment: i just editesd answer with sample example...can you mention the actual format you want the result for example : 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3'  ?

Comment: "2019-11-15T03:22:45.254+01:00" This string needs to be saved into a timestamp(6) database column

Comment: is it this format :  TIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM'  ?  i have updated the answer

Comment: Format must be `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM'`